# preserve list elements as names in lapply function

Tags: r

Say I have the following:

```
seq<-c(2,3,4)
added<-lapply(1:length(seq),function(i){
       seq[i]+1
       }
)

> added
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 5
```

How do I use the list elements in `seq` to name the list elements of 'added'?

i.e.

```
> added
  [[2]]
  [1] 3

  [[3]]
  [1] 4

  [[4]]
  [1] 5
```

thank you

*ACCEPTED SOLUTION* from @akrun

```
seq<-c(2,3,4)
added<-setNames(lapply(1:length(seq),function(i){
seq[i]+1
}
),seq1)
```

Comment: `setNames(added, seq)`  BTW, `seq` is a function, so it is better to name the object as `seq1` or so...

Comment: If you need to fill the elements based on the index, perhaps `lst <- vector('list', max(seq)); lst[seq] <- as.list(seq+1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
 added <- setNames(added, seq)
```

Or

```
 names(added) <- seq
```

Comment: I have used setNames(). Will put the solution in my question

Comment: @brucezeppelin Thanks, I was initially a bit confused by the index.

Answer (score 0):

`library(purrr)
seq<-c(2,3,4)
set_names(seq, seq_along(seq))`

or

`seq %>% 
set_names(seq_along(.))`